# HTML breaking up in Outlook but renders well without breakup in browsers

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have developed an HTML mailer which has to render in outlook it work fine in all browsers but breaks when I render in Outlook. Please see the below link to get the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8xFn/

```
    <body>
     <table class="mailer-document" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td class="header">
    <img src="top green and blue lines.jpg" alt="header"  />
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr class="content-bg">
    <td>
    <p class="welcomecontent">Hi <span class="username">KELLY DEANNA,</span></p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="content-bg">
    <td>
        <p class="welcomecontent"><span>Federation Request has been raised by</span> 
       <b>Renu V Menon</b>          <span>and its in your cart for approval</span></p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="content-bg">
    <td>
    <p class="details">Following are the details of the request for your reference:</p>
    </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
   <table class="details-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td class="details-left" width="185px">
    <span class="RequestID">
    Request ID
    </span>
</td>
<td class="details-right" width="auto">
<span class="Details">: 30147633 </span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="details-left" width="185px">
    <p class="RequestID">
    Associate ID
    </p>
</td>
<td class="details-right" width="auto">
<p class="Details">: 394163 </p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="details-left" width="185px">
    <p class="RequestID">
    Project Name
    </p>
</td>
<td class="details-right" width="auto">
<p class="Details">: Domain </p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="details-left" width="185px">
    <p class="RequestID">
    Domain Name
    </p>
</td>
<td class="details-right" width="auto">
<p class="Details">: <a href="#">Domain@tech.com</a> </p>
</td>
</tr>

    </table>
       </body>
```

Comment: best to use inline styles for emailers, also not sure you can use html5 elements, floats or pseudo selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table, tr and td tags add:

```
border="0"
```

and add this into your head:

```
<style type="text/css">
   table {border-collapse: collapse;}
</style>
```

I hope this helps :)